# Can we extract the names of datasets used in a Pipeline for use within the Pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

We have a table (Classification) with dataset names and security classifications. As we perform ETL tasks on these datasets, the output files need to be assigned the maximum value of security classification of its components.

datasetA and datasetB are classified as 1 and 4 resectively.
dataFlow1 joins the two datasets.  The resultant dataset must be logged in Classification with a 4 to preserve the highest level of classification.

I tried building pipelines that start with a data flow, followed by a GetMetadata activity to find the name of all datasets used in the Pipeline, expecting to get a list of the names that I could use to query the table.  I did not get a list of dataset names.

I tried a similar approach with a Notebook, hoping to get all the names.  I was unable to get one up and running.

Answer (score 0):

To extract the names of datasets used in a Pipeline for use within the Pipeline you need to use Rest API of [Pipelines-Get(ADF)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipelines/get?tabs=HTTP&tryIt=true&source=docs#code-try-0), [Pipelines-Get(Synapse)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/synapse/data-plane/pipeline/get-pipeline?tabs=HTTP)

**You can follow below steps:**

- Take a web activity and use the Rest Api to get details about pipeline from above doc.

```json
--For ADF
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/{factoryName}/pipelines/{pipelineName}?api-version=2018-06-01

--For Synapse
{endpoint}/pipelines/{pipelineName}?api-version=2020-12-01
```

[image]

- Then take for each activity and pass range to get dataset from activities. Here I want datasets of first two activities, so I used `@range(0,2)`
  [image]
- Inside foreach loop take two **Append variables** and for first variable pass expression for source datasets as `@activity('Web1').output.properties.activities[item()].inputs[0].referenceName` and for second variable pass expression for sink datasets as `@activity('Web1').output.properties.activities[item()].outputs[0].referenceName`
  [image]
  [image]
- And you will get array for both input and output datasets as below:
  [image]